# oWhy does eshell display a black screen?

Tags: emacs

In eshell, i want to install mew from freebsd ports:

```
 $uname -a
 FreeBSD mybsd.zsoft.com 9.0-RELEASE-p3 FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE-p3 #0: Fri Jul  6 11:09:08 CST 2012     ***@mybsd.zsoft.com:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/MYKERNEL  i386
 $ cd /usr/ports/mail/mew
 $ sudo make install clean
```

After inputting root's password, the eshell window became black.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I should use "*sudo" iinstead of "sudo"